# Can I create a texture attachment with a pointer of dma_buf?

Tags: opengl-es, textures, dma, fbo

In OpenGL ES，we can Create a texture for a framebuffer like this:

```
unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Then we can attach it to the framebuffer:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
```

My question is: Can I create a texture for a framebuffer with pointer of dma_buf? Like this:

```
shm_handle_t handle = dma_buf_malloc(size);
void* vaddr = dma_get_address(handle);

unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// vaddr instead of NULL
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 800, 600, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vaddr);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
```

Comment: glTexImage2D takes data pointer from system memory not GPU memory. Therefore, you should copy DMA buffer to system memory and pass this copy to glTexImage2D.

Comment: I don't want to create a input texture, but a output texture which attached to a fbo as colorTexture. The dma_buf is a block of memory both accessed by CPU and GPU.

Comment: glTexImage2D expects a pointer to system memory data, and it does not directly accept a DMA buffer handle or GPU specific memory pointers. That is the reason you should copy to system memory if you want to use glTexImage2D.

Comment: Maybe it depends OpenGL ES implementation of device. I know, OpenGL ES on TDA4 can do this. User can set a ShareMemory (TDA4) pointer in glTexImage2D. And GPU render to the color texture which is associated with the SharedMemory.